# Append form input to external URL post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, post, haml

I feel like I'm missing something really simple here. I have a search form on a Rails 4 app that takes inputted keywords and then needs to append them to an external URL.

If the inputted keywords are: "banana orange"

Then the desired URL would be: http://example.com/search/node/banana%20%orange

Here is my current form in HAML:

```
 .form-group.form-group-sm
   %form{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :action => "http://example.com/search/node/", :method => "post"}
     %input.form-control{placeholder: "Search site...", :type => "text"}
     %input.form-control{:type => "submit"}
```

When I click submit, I am redirected to just "http://example.com/search/node/".

How can I get the inputted parameters from the form appended to the URL in the correct format? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you use 'GET' for this, instead of 'POST'. Because the search action is mainly reading data, and not changing any data.

Therefore you would want to change:

```
%form{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :action => "http://example.com/search/node/", :method => "post"}
```

Into

```
%form{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :action => "http://example.com/search/node/", :method => "get"}
```

In your controller, you access the `banana%20orange`, by

```
def search
  puts params[:search_query]
  # => this will show you "banana orange"
end
```

Just make sure you change `:search_query` into the name you passed in the routes:

```
# routes.rb
# I.E you have the following
get '/search/node/:search_query' => 'controller_name#action_name'
```

Also change controller_name and action_name above accordingly.

### Update:

You would also want to change

```
%input.form-control{placeholder: "Search site...", :type => "text"}
```

Into

```
%input.form-control{name: 'search_query', placeholder: "Search site...", :type => "text"}
```

Or  I would more prefer:

```
= text_field_tag :search_query, placeholder: "Search site...", class: 'form-control'
```

### Update

Little Javascript Hack to change the URL after clicking submit button / pressing enter (I couldn't think of anything that doesn't involve JS to solve this):

```
%form{"accept-charset" => "UTF-8", :action => "http://example.com/search/node/", :method => "get", onsubmit: "window.location.href=$(this).attr('action') + $('input[name=search-query]').val(); return false;"}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm guessing I also need to add :search_query into the form. Would that be an attribute to the first %input.form-control?

Comment: @Brit200313 Hi I forgot to take into account that this would need I think a javascript to change the url. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you! I need to remove "?search_query=" and change the spaces into %20 and the + into %2B.

Comment: @Brit200313 sorry for the delay. Was busy in the workplace :) I updated the answer to add some little JS magic :)

Comment: I just solved it by sending it through a Controller to parse the URL. Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: @Brit200313 You're very welcome :) By the way, you could mark this now solved.